# Flask app with Mysql DB / cyrillic characters are not recognized

Tags: mysql, flask, encoding, cyrillic

I want to use Cyrillic characters with my simple web app (flask with MySQL DB).

DB charset is set = cp1251 / collation = cp1251_general_ci
Charset/collation is specified during application connection to DB as follows:

```
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{creds["user"]}:{creds["pass"]}@{creds["host"]}:{creds["port"]}/{creds["dbname"]}?**charset=cp1251&collation=cp1251_general_ci**'
```

p.s. It's a small flask web app (pet project). Btw before I used Postgres with no problems (no bothering about charsets/collation). But I had to migrate to MySQL as Postgres is expensive to host @ AWS RDS. So I migrated to MySQL @ some free hosting.

When entering Latin characters it works / when entering Cyrillic letters it stores "????"

Cannot understand what's causing the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). Further reading at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/).

Comment: Used utf8mb4. It helped finally. Thank you!

Comment: More on Question marks in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored